# Does Swift has built-in logarithm function?

Tags: swift, math

I want to calculate `log(2)8` in Swift without import modules. I can't find any function in the Document.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the `log2(:Double)` or `log2f(:Float)` methods from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1557246-log2), available by e.g. importing `UIKit` or `Foundation`:

```
func log2(x: Double) -> Double
func log2f(x: Float) -> Float
```

E.g., in a Playground

```
print(log2(8.0)) // 3.0
```

---

*(Edit addition w.r.t. your comment below)*

If you want to compute your custom-base log function, you can make use of the following change-of-base relation for logarithms

[image]

Hence, for e.g. calculating `log3`, you could write the following function

```
func log3(val: Double) -> Double {
    return log(val)/log(3.0)
}

print(log3(9.0)) // "2.0"
```

Or, simply a custom-base log function:

```
func logC(val: Double, forBase base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(val)/log(base)
}

print(logC(9.0, forBase: 3.0)) // "2.0"
print(logC(16.0, forBase: 4.0)) // "2.0"
```

Comment: And how to calculate log3(9.0) ?

Comment: @Utopia Updated my answer to include a general case.

Comment: P.S. `Foundation` is a part of Swift now, not Xcode  https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2a5bc4d8a0b073532e60410682f5eb8f00144870/Sources/Foundation/CGFloat.swift#L737-L760

Comment: @BenLeggiero Thanks for the prompt! The linked functions describe the `CGFloat` interface, though, but I can't really find where the underlying `Float` and `Double` overloads are defined. I see them invoked within the bodies of the `CGFloat` overloads: `log(x.native)`. It seems the native `Float` and `Double` overloads where supposed to be implemented as part of [SE-0246](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0246-mathable.md), but apparently that has been temporarily put on hold due to [source compatibility consequences](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/23789).

Comment: There are some [buildin intrinsics in core/stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/061c6d0654e5ab6a0e616772016b6ff8463dc1dc/stdlib/public/core/BuiltinMath.swift#L42-L55), but these are internal (`_log...`). Afaics the `Float` and `Double` overloads are in `swift-numerics` (_"[...] is a standalone library separate from the core Swift project."_), particularly in [`Float+Real.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/blob/master/Sources/RealModule/Float%2BReal.swift) and [`Double+Real.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/blob/master/Sources/RealModule/Double%2BReal.swift)

Comment: Perhaps `swift-numerics` (`import Numerics`) is the reference I should specify nowadays?

Comment: Nice investigation! Since it seems `import Numerics` doesn't compile, and `swift-numerics` seems to be just a part of Swift's `Foundation`, I'd still say just `import Foundation`. I just tested on macOS and on Ubuntu simply by importing Foundation and it worked fine: `import Foundation; print(log(Double(12.0)))`